# Datetime x axis in bokeh.charts.Area

Tags: python, bokeh

Why I plot my data with a `datetime` series as x axis, it is interpreted as a `datetime` value, but the wrong one: my 2016 times are interpreted as  milliseconds after 1970-1-1. Code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.charts import Area, show, output_file

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['date'] = [datetime(2016, 1, 1), datetime(2016, 1, 2), datetime(2016, 1, 3)]
df['v1'] = [1, 2, 3]
df['v2'] = [4, 4, 3]

p = Area(df, x='date', y=['v1', 'v2'], title="Area Chart",
         legend="top_left", xscale='datetime', stack=True,
         xlabel='time', ylabel='values')

output_file("area.html", title="Area Chart")
show(p)
```

[image: Area chart screenshot]

Is there a way I can get `bokeh.charts.Area` recognize my `datetime` data, or do I have to construct the plot myself using `figure()`?

Additional data: bokeh 0.11.1 on Python 2.7

Comment: This is very weird and could potentially be a bug when with your environment conditions. I've tried the example with bokeh `0.11.1` and the current `master` branch with bokeh python 2 and 3 without being able to reproduce the issue. I suggest to open an issue and provide also more info about your platform and evironment.

Comment: You are right, something is fishy about my local setup. On my home computer, I couldn't reproduce the issue either. Will answer myself or delete the question, depending on what the resolution looks like.

Comment: @FabioPliger: I fixed the issue. I was using ``pip install -e .``, and that has the nasty habbit of re-using the `<packagename>.egg-info` directory, if it exists. So if you update your dependencies, that is silently ignored. If you want to post and answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @FabioPliger: There was more stuff going on. The egg-info was one problem, but another one was bytes/unicode confusion with bokeh under Python 2.7. Will answer myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the `from __future__ import unicode` statement.* Removing the line fixed the problem.

The core issue is that the the `x='date'` keyword argument must be bytes. Otherwise bokeh will not find the key in the dataframe. It does not show a warning or error in this case, it just silently replaces it with a numerical index (0, 1, 2, 3), which is interpreted as milliseconds by the date axis.

---

* Left out of the original question, because the same problem also surfaced after some pip confusion with leftover .egg-info directories.